# How can i change date format via sql

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-date-functions

I have saved date in my database in `12-Oct-2021 12:27:53 pm` this format. But I need to change it to `2021-10-12`. How can i do it via SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE('12-Oct-2021 12:27:53 pm', '%d-%b-%Y %r'))
```

More about STR_TO_DATE [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/).

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '12-Oct-2021 12:27:53 pm', 106)
```

Should give you:

> 2021-10-12

See if that works for you.

Comment: I got an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''12-Oct-2021 12:13:41 am', 106)' at line 1

Comment: You get an error because this is the [MS-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) version, The 106 is explained here [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)   (which is not needed in this case! (conversion to date))

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 23);
```

This will convert the date into yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: You get an error because this is the [MS-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) version, The 23 is explained here [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  (which is needed in this case, because conversion is done towards a (var)char))

Comment: The question is tagged with "mariadb" not "ms-sql"